# How to Disable checkBox, if it already true?

Tags: javascript

How to disable checkBox when it is already true. I have my code but it check and uncheck both. Whenever user click on unmark checkbox then it will become Marked. If it is already marked than to disable it. Please review it and help me to disable checkbox if it is already True.

```
colDef.splice(colDef.length - 0, 0, {
  "width": "140px",
  displayName: '<div class="hasHelp"><span class="col-title">Discount Given' +
    '</span><span class=" fa AP-fa-help tooltipster grid-header-question" id="34897945" ></span></div>',
  field: 'is_claimed',
  name: 'is_claimed',
  orderable: true,
  enableCellEdit: false,
  className: "dt-nowrap",
  Resizable: "false",

  render: (function(data, type, full, meta) {
    if (this.doReturn)
      return data;
    var ed = null;
    // if (full['enabledisableItem'])
    // ed = full['enabledisableItem'];
    // else

    ed = new BooleanDataTableEditor({
      editorColumnId: 'enabledisableClaimItem',
      columnData: data,
      columnType: type,
      columnFull: full,
      columnMeta: meta,
      parent: this,
      checkedValue: true,
      uncheckedValue: false,
      // validateValue :
      // scope2.validateAmoutValue('Base
      // price'),
      strutsController: this.getStrutsController(),
      columnRenderer: 'currencyColumnRenderer',
      OnAfterValueSaved: 'itemEnabledDisalbed'
    });

    full['enabledisableItem'] = ed;

    var retVal = '<div class="enableDisableCheck">' +
      ed.build() + '</div>';

    return retVal;

  }).bind(this)
});
```

Comment: What framework are you using? React? What do the arguments `data, type, full, meta` contain?

Comment: tried to set the disabled attribute in HTML?  `<input type="checkbox" ... disabled>`

Comment: It's angular. data = true, type = 'display', full contains the data from database and meta is column and row number.